# Conditionals not working properly in Django Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In the code below, educationData is an zip of a database query result and a range function.

I have got a completely similar conditional in the same HTML page. Now the problem is that, every time just one of them works, i.e if the conditional below works then the other one does not.

```
{% if educationData != 'unavailable' %}
{% for edu, counter in educationData %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="circ"></div>
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{counter}}" aria-expanded="false"aria controls="collapse{{counter}}" class="collapsed expand-date">{{edu.year}}</a>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{counter}}">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <span aria-controls="collapse{{counter}}">
                <span class="accordion-heading">{{edu.education_type}}</span>
                </span>

            </h4>
              </div>
                <div id="collapse{{counter}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{counter}}">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                  <h4 class="timeline-title">Started <span><strong>{{edu.education_type}}</strong></span> at <span><strong>{{edu.institution_name}}</strong></span></h4>
                  <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>{{edu.what_did_you_do_there}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if educationData == 'unavailable' %}
  <p>Not Available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Please help. Stuck :(

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is working and what isn't? The conditions are opposite, so naturally only one of them can be true at any one time. However you should really be using `else` here instead of a separate `if`.

Comment: Not this pair of ifs. I have got another pair of ifs. The problem is, that if the above pair of ifs work then the other does not work.

Comment: So you're saying your problem is with a totally different bit of code which you haven't shown? How do you expect us to help in that case?

Answer (score 0):

try using `{% elif %}`?

```
{% if educationData != 'unavailable' %}
    <loop here>
{% elif educationData == 'unavailable' %}
    <other html here>
{% endif %}
```